# Certain content not in a fixed position with resized window

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a website for class and I am completely stumped on how to fix my problem. I've read and read trying to figure out how to correct this problem but I am very confused and cannot seem to figure out my situation. As far as my webpage is concerned I am trying to figure out how to keep my main content fixated when My browser is re-sized. Here are some photos of my issue.

[image]
[image]

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>About</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2 align="left">

<div class="container">
<h5>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <a href="default.html">Home</a><br /><br />
  <a href="about.html">About</a><br /><br />
  <a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a><br /><br />
  <a href="dining.html">Dining</a><br /><br />
  <a href="nightlife.html">Night Life</a><br /><br />
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br /><br />
 </h5></div>
 <!--Navigation bar -->
<div class="content">
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="subscription">
<form>
 Subscribe to our Newsletter: <input type="text" name="CustEmail" id="CustEmail"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
 </form>
 </div>
<!--Subscription -->



 </body>
 <style type="text/css">

  body
  { 
  background-image:url(about.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:fixed;
  background-size:;
  text-align:right


  }
  .container { width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    padding: 1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:165px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .content {
width: 64%;
height: 62%;
padding: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 24%;
overflow: scroll;
visibility: visible;
left: 27%;
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
    }
    #subscription {
position: absolute;
top: 7%;
left: 25%;
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
    }
    </style> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Please share some code too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the position attributes to fixed? 
What do you want to happen when the window is resized?

Comment: I was trying to have my content in a fixed position rather than it resizing along with the window

Comment: If you need to clarify something, try to post a comment before an answer, especially if your answer will be this short.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look closely at your CSS, in particular, the following properties of `<div>` elements:

```
z-index
overflow
white-space
```

Also, try to specify `width` property in % (instead of px), so resizing will be more predictable. That might be the answer. Regards, AB